# $wpdb->insert_id doesn't return anything

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm inserting rows on custom table with `$wpdb->insert`. Everything works as expected unless I can't get any id with `$wpdb->insert_id` after the query.

Here is my function  (with some modifications to hide true data like db table ):

```
function create_post() {
    global $wpdb, $currentuser;
    $wpdb->insert('my_table',array('author' => $currentuser['user_id']),array('%d'));
    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;
    return $id;
}
```

My row is perfectly inserted and I see no error with `$wpdb->show_errors();` nor `$wpdb->print_error();`.

In my database I've an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id column of course.

Any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: Do you use a foreign key ?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy no there is no foreign key !

Comment: May be there is something you missed. Try creating the `my_table` again in the database to be sure there is no problem at that side. Then test the value `$wpdb->rows_affected` is it `1` which means it is working fine?

Comment: Yes I've recreated the table twice and I can confirm that the query works perfectly, the row is efficiently inserted in the table and I can see the query in the logs. There is no error returned, everything works perfectly unless $wpdb->insert_id returning an empty string.

Comment: What does `$wpdb->rows_affected` return ?

Comment: $wpdb->rows_affected return nothing as well, but what it's supposed to return ? I can't find this class variable in WP doc

Comment: At my end It returns 1 (meaning there is a row inserted). it is a property of the $wpdb object. ([wpdb source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/))

Comment: How about doing this: `$num =$wpdb->insert('my_table',array('author' => $currentuser['user_id']),array('%d'));` assigning the return value of the insert to the variable `$num` ? then check its value. It should be `1`

Comment: Thanks to you I've made some other tests and I'm now able to say that the error don't come from my function but the way I get the result of my function. I'm passing it through ajax and it seems that the error come from here.

Comment: Great. If you didn't solve it yet and would like to post the ajax code to the question ... there would be no problem.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim ! My issue is fixed, I was using die() instead of wp_die() at the end of my ajax function. I don't know why wp_die() is needed since die() is enough for all of my other ajax functions but anyway my problem is solved! Thanks a lot Ibrahim for your help!